# PowerPivot: Add one product to another

Tags: powerpivot, dax

We are combining products, and want to get an idea of what demand may look like for the combined products vs what we had before. Here is some sample data:

A mapping of where products will be going called `SKU_Mapping`:

```
Old Product | New Product  
    1       |    2  
    3       |    4
```

Then I have some historical sales information called Sales:

```
Product | Quantity  
   1    |    5  
   2    |    10  
   3    |    3  
   4    |    7
```

I also have a table with all the SKUs to link my two other tables together called `Master_SKU`

```
Product  
   1  
   2  
   3  
   4
```

I have relationships between `'Master_SKU'[Product]` to `'Sales'[Product]` and from `'Master_SKU'[Product]` to `'SKU_Mapping[Old Product]`

I am trying to get an output like this

```
New Product | Old Product | Original Quantity | New Quantity  
    2       |     1       |        10         |      15  
    4       |     3       |        7          |      10
```

I cannot figure out how to write a formula that says, *take the quantity of the new product and add it to the quantity of the old product*. I have tried a bunch of different operators but for the life of me I cannot figure it out. Any insights or suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

[image]

Here's how:

I set up three tables exactly as you described, with the relationships as you described. Then I opened the SKU_Mapping table and I added a column:

```
Old Product Qty = CALCULATE(sumx(Sales,Sales[Quantity]),filter(Sales,Sales[Product]=SKU_Mapping[Old Product]))
```

...and another column:

```
New Product Qty = CALCULATE(sumx(Sales,Sales[Quantity]),filter(Sales,Sales[Product]=SKU_Mapping[New Product]))
```

...and one last column:

```
Total Qty = SKU_Mapping[Old Product Qty]+SKU_Mapping[New Product Qty]
```